# "ERROR MESSAGE: Requires installation of untrusted packages"

Tags: apt, virtualbox, software-center

I'm running Ubuntu 13.04 in VirtualBox 4.3.20. I keep getting the error message shown in the title when I try to download anything in the Software Center.

I tried changing servers in "Software and Updates"

and that didn't work.  I typed `sudo apt-get update` into the console and this is what it gave me:

```
Hit http://repo.steampowered.com precise Release.gpg
Hit http://repo.steampowered.com precise Release                               
Hit http://repo.steampowered.com precise/steam Sources                         
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com raring Release.gpg                                
Hit http://repo.steampowered.com precise/steam amd64 Packages                  
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring Release.gpg                               
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com raring Release                                    
Hit http://repo.steampowered.com precise/steam i386 Packages                   
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates Release.gpg                       
Hit http://toolbelt.heroku.com ./ Release.gpg                                  
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports Release.gpg                     
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com raring/main Sources/DiffIndex                     
Hit http://toolbelt.heroku.com ./ Release                                      
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-security Release.gpg                      
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com raring/main amd64 Packages/DiffIndex              
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring Release                                   
Hit http://toolbelt.heroku.com ./ Packages                                     
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com raring/main i386 Packages/DiffIndex               
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates Release                           
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports Release                         
Hit https://private-ppa.launchpad.net raring Release.gpg                       
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-security Release                          
Hit https://private-ppa.launchpad.net raring Release                           
Hit https://private-ppa.launchpad.net raring/main amd64 Packages               
Ign http://toolbelt.heroku.com ./ Translation-en_US                            
Ign http://toolbelt.heroku.com ./ Translation-en                               
Hit https://private-ppa.launchpad.net raring/main i386 Packages      
Ign http://repo.steampowered.com precise/steam Translation-en_US     
Ign http://repo.steampowered.com precise/steam Translation-en        
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com raring/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com raring/main Translation-en
Err http://extras.ubuntu.com raring/main Sources
  404  Not Found
Err http://extras.ubuntu.com raring/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://extras.ubuntu.com raring/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
Ign https://private-ppa.launchpad.net raring/main Translation-en_US
Ign https://private-ppa.launchpad.net raring/main Translation-en
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/main Sources    
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/restricted Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/universe Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/multiverse Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/restricted amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/universe amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/multiverse amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/restricted i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/universe i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/multiverse i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/main Translation-en
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/multiverse Translation-en
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/restricted Translation-en
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/universe Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/universe Translation-en
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/main Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/restricted Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/universe Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/multiverse Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/restricted amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/universe amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/restricted i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/universe i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/multiverse i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/main Translation-en
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/multiverse Translation-en
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/restricted Translation-en
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/universe Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/universe Translation-en
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/main Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/restricted Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/universe Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/multiverse Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/restricted amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/universe amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/multiverse amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/restricted i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/universe i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/multiverse i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/main Translation-en
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/multiverse Translation-en
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/restricted Translation-en
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/universe Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/universe Translation-en
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-security/main Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-security/restricted Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-security/universe Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-security/multiverse Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-security/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-security/restricted amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-security/universe amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-security/multiverse amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-security/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-security/restricted i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-security/universe i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-security/multiverse i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-security/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-security/main Translation-en
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-security/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-security/multiverse Translation-en
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-security/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-security/restricted Translation-en
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-security/universe Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-security/universe Translation-en
W: Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/restricted/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/universe/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/multiverse/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/universe/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-updates/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-updates/restricted/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-updates/universe/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-updates/multiverse/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-updates/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-updates/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-updates/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-updates/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-updates/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-updates/universe/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-updates/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-backports/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-backports/restricted/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-backports/universe/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-backports/multiverse/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-backports/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-backports/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-backports/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-backports/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-backports/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-backports/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-backports/universe/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-backports/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-security/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-security/restricted/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-security/universe/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-security/multiverse/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-security/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-security/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-security/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-security/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-security/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-security/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-security/universe/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-security/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this?  Thx in advance.

Comment: Ubuntu 13.04 is end of life and not supported now. To upgrade your Ubuntu see [How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-old-unsupported-release)

Answer (score 0):

Try to install the below,

```
sudo apt-get install update-manager-core

sudo do-release-upgrade
```

After doing so use `sudo apt-get update`

Comment: I tried your commands but nothings seems to have changed.  Would you like me to post the console log above?  EDIT: Sorry, I don't have enough character space to post it.